# Python 3 - ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Situation:**
Given this project structure:

```
project/
  app/
    __init__.py (empty)
    stamp.py
  tests/
    test.py
  main.py
```

In `main.py` and `test.py` I am trying to import the functionality of `stamp.py` via:

```
from app.stamp import Timestamp
```

`Timestamp` gets imported in `main.py` but not in `test.py` where I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'app'
```

**Question**:
How can I in python 3.5 import functionality of `stamp.py` in `test.py`?

Comment: how are you invoking test.py?

Comment: via Terminal: python tests/test.py 
it is nothing fancy in test.py just trying to figure how to do the imports

Comment: How are you calling stamp.py inside test.py?

Comment: from app.stamp import Timestamp  \n   

t = Timestamp()

Comment: does folder tests have file \__init__.py ?

Comment: try going up one level and running `python project/tests/test.py`? I always run into these import issues with pycharm and basically keep tweaking the interpreter path until it starts working.

Comment: No _init_.py in test folder. Added it but still get the same error.

Comment: @BAH same error with `python project/tests/test.py` but no error with `python project/main.py`

Comment: @DavidR what about using the import from the answer (`from project.app.stamp import Timestamp`) and then running the test from upper folder. Also make sure you have `__init__.py` files in both `project/` and `test`, not just `test` folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure your folder tests contains __init__.py

Below code appends the path of your project `project` to `sys.path` in `test.py`

python will go through to search the modules and files in your `project`

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/project")
from app.stamp import Timestamp
```

Comment: Thx all. As recommended I imported `sys` as well `os` and added the following code to test.py `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('.'))`. It works also without all `__init__.py` files

Comment: @DavidR  glad to know it helps:)  \__init__.py makes a regular directory treated as a package

Comment: Do `__init__.py` files provide any benefits in python 3 where they are not required any more

Comment: @DavidR  you are right, Python3 doesnt require it anymore. i am still working on Python2.7 so always make the init file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `project/` is in your [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), put and `__init__.py` file in the `project/` directory and then you will be able to call `from project.app.stamp import Timestamp`.